# Adding items into array Laravel using for loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am trying to get all `categories` that have `products` from the database and push them into another array.

I have four 3 `categories` and two of them have `products`.

Here is my code:

```
$categories = Category::all();
$count = count($categories);
$categoriesWithProducts = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if($categories[$i]->products->count() > 0) {
        array_push($categoriesWithProducts, $categories[$i]);
    }
    return  response()->json($categoriesWithProducts);
}
```

I get an array with just one item instead of two.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: use $i <= $count

Comment: try `if(count($categories[$i]->products) > 0) {`

Comment: Move your `return` so it's after (outside) the loop. Currently, it will always return the data after the first iteration.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i actually missed that. Thanks it solved it.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although error is obvious (mentioned in comment) you could rewrite the whole thing:

```
$categories = Category::withCount('products')->get(); // you load count to not make n+1 queries

$categoriesWithProducts = $categories->filter(function($category) {
   return $category->products_count > 0
})->values();

return response()->json(categoriesWithProducts);
```

Of course you could make it even simpler:

```
return response()->json(Category::withCount('products')->get()
                     ->filter(function($category) {
                         return $category->products_count > 0
                      })->values()
                   );
```

But in fact the best way would be using [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) so you could use:

```
return response()->json(Category::has('products')->get());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, quite enlightening.

Comment: instead of using array I'd recommend a collection.  $categoriesWithProducts = collect();  Then in you're loop do $categoriesWithProducts->push($categories[$i]);  and then return $categoriesWithProducts;